# Java 8 -> sort List depending on other List

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I do have two java.util.List which e.g. looks like this:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = ...
MyObject myObject1 = ...
MyObject myObject2 = ...
MyObject myObject3 = ...
MyObject myObject4 = ...
MyObject myObject5 = ...
myObjects.add(myObjet1);
...
```

and the second List looks like this:

```
List<MyObject> otherListObjects = ...
MyObject myObject1 = ...
MyObject myObject5 = ...
```

Now my aim is to have a list where **myObject1** and **myObject5** are at the first two places and than the others.
Is there a simple possibility to do this in Java 8?

Comment: Why there a reason why you need Java 8? And which feature are you refering to, in specific? This can easily be done by creating a new list, call `newList.addAll(otherListObjects); myObjects.removeAll(otherListObjects(); newList.addAll(myObjects);`

Comment: Write a comparator that gets the index of the wo compared objects in otherList, or Integer.MAX_VALUE if not found, then compare these two integer values.

Comment: so `otherListObjects` defines the `n-first` elements in the new list? if so do these objects override hashcode/equals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could sort the items of `myObjects` according to the index they appear in `myOtherObjects`:

```
myObjects.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> {
    int ind  = myOtherObjects.indexOf(s);
    if (ind >= 0) {
        return ind;
    }
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}));
```

A cool variant on this was suggested by Malte Hartwig. It utilizes Java's integer arithmetic underflow, so that if the object isn't found in `myOtherObjects`, adding `-1` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` will underflow and produce `2147483647`:

```
myObjects.sort(
    Comparator.comparingInt(s -> myOtherObjects.indexOf(s) + Integer.MIN_VALUE));
```

If you don't care about the internal order inside `myOtherObjects`, this can be greatly simplified:

```
myObjects.sort(Comparator.comparing(myOtherObjects::contains).reversed());
```

Comment: For those, thinking the `+ Integer.MIN_VALUE` looks “too magic”, there is the option to use `Comparator.comparingLong(s -> Integer.toUnsignedLong(myOtherObjects.indexOf(s)))` instead. Semantically, it’s the same; see also [`Integer.compareUnsigned(…)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.compareUnsigned%28int%2Cint%29)…

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure from reading your question, whether you need the first list sorted or a new list. Here are two approaches for creating a new list (for sorting the existing one, look at Mureinik's answer).

If you insist on Java 8, try Streams:

```
Stream.of(otherListObjects, myObjects)
      .flatMap(Collecttion::stream)
      .distinct
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is quite simple to do this with old-fashioned Java, though:

```
List<MyObject> newList = new ArrayList<>();
newList.addAll(otherListObjects);
for (MyObject o : myObjects) {
    if (!newList.contains(o))
        newList.add(o);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sort the first list. That concatenates the second one with the first one.

Comment: @JBNizet Does Op say they want the first list sorted? I read a couple of times.

Comment: Right there, in the title: *Java 8 -> sort List depending on other List*

Comment: @JBNizet fair point, I concentrated on _my aim is to have a list..._, which sound as if they want a new list.